# AWS RDS Postgres not accessible via HTTP(S)

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, http, postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to deploy an app that queries my postgres db, hosted on aws rds, and needs to be publicly available via HTTP. To achieve that, I changed the connection type in the inbound rules for the db's security group (ticked Publicly Accessible) to HTTP (port 80) or HTTPS (port 443). But when querying the db I'm getting:

> HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   - HTTPS TCP 443 ::/0    : OperationalError: could
>   not connect to server: Operation timed out    Is the server running on
>   host "prescribinguk.czm1h03t4mrp.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
>   (3.127.191.236) and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 443?
>   The same response for HTTP port 80 or when replacing 0.0.0.0/0 with my IP.

When the inbound rule in my security group is set to connect to my public IP or from anywhere the DB is accessible:

> PostgreSQL    TCP 5432    : OK 
>   PostgreSQL    TCP 5432    0.0.0.0/0   - and   ::/0    -: OK

Can you help me detect what I'm missing out in setting HTTP(S) as a connection type

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is completely unclear. It is very natural, AWS RDS will not accept HTTPS traffic. The only common part for both protocols may be SSL/TLS.  PostgreSQL and HTTP traffic are different by design. Trying to answer. You have to make two different security groups. One for application. The other for database. Moreover, I highly recommend you removing public access to your database as it looks like it is accessible from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The database is secured and accessible as read only for users that will run my script. I was checking the HTTP access for a specific deployment but now realize that this is not possible. Thanks for your help.